# What is this actually in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am working in Selenium, and this question is more specific to Java rather than Selenium.

The example I am providing is Selenium WebDriver ExplicitWait,

```
new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) 
        {
            return d.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
        }});
```

What he is exactly Doing ? How he is writing Logic without Assigning a Reference to an object to the class ExpectedCondition ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is happening here is the creation of an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) that inherits from `ExpectedCondition`. In the body of this class he is then overriding the method `apply(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

That is an [anonymous class](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~tmh/courses/allJava/Anonymous.html) which extends `ExpectedCondition`.

```
Collections.sort (aList, 
new Comparator () { // implements the IF 
public int compare (ObjectType o1, ObjectType o2 ) throws ..{ 
.... implementation for compare() 
} // end of compare() 
} // end of Comparator implementation
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an anonymous inner class.  the general form is:

```
class OuterClass {
  void method() {
    MyInterfaceOrClass innerClass = new MyInterfaceOrClass() {
      @Override
      public void methodToOverride() {
          /* code */
      }
    };
  }
 }
```

It defined a new class with no name(*) that extends or implements the named class or interface and includes the overriden method(s) in the new class definition.  The definition is used just for the one element being created.

(*) Okay, it really does have a name, like Outerclass$12, but you aren't supposed to rely on that being the same from compile to compile.  If you need a class name, this is the wrong syntax to use.